# Cómo actualizar una lista UL generada con datos de Firebase en Javascript sin que esta se duplique

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Estoy haciendo una lista con datos que obtengo de Firebase, todo funciona bien hasta que actualizo un dato en Firebase. Al actualizar un dato se genera una nueva lista abajo de la anterior con los datos actualizados, y cada vez que se actualiza un dato se genera una lista adicional.

La idea es hacer que la lista de actualice dentro de la misma, sin tener que generar una lista nueva a cada rato o generar una lista nueva y eliminar la anterior...

Este es el código que estoy usando

```
var content = '';  
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref().child("A_Usuarios").orderByChild("TipoUsuario")
.equalTo("Usuario1")
.on('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        console.log(snapshot.key)
        content +='<ul>';  
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var val = data.val();
            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';
            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';
            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';
            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';
            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';  
        });
        content +='</ul>';
        $("#A_Usuarios").empty().html(content);
    }
});
```

Espero alguien entienda el problema y pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Haz un `console.log(content)` antes de insertarlo en el **HTML** para ver lo que estás inyectando en el **DOM**. Tras verlo deberías encontrar el problema.

Comment: Esta es la lista que obtengo en console.log(content) cuando ejecuto este código... <ul><li>Starn</li><li>Telur</li><li>Chil</li><li>Econ</li><li>Chac</li></ul>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es el `content +='<ul>'` que estás ejecutando, ya que siempre le vuelve a agregar una lista, la corrección sería simple, siempre que exista un snapshot **content debe ser igual a < ul >** y de ahí empezar a poblarlo otra vez:

```
var content = '';  
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref().child("A_Usuarios").orderByChild("TipoUsuario")
.equalTo("Usuario1")
.on('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        console.log(snapshot.key)
        content = '<ul>';  
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var val = data.val();
            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';
            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';
            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';
            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';
            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';  
        });
        content +='</ul>';
        $("#A_Usuarios").empty().html(content);
    }
});
```

Espero que sea lo que necesitas.

Comment: Tienes razón, ese es el problema, pero cuando elimino el + entonces no se genera la tabla... Por eso todavía no encuentro la solución.

Comment: Existe alguna forma de generar la lista ul aparte de este código y rellenarla externamente con los datos que obtengo de Firebase eliminando los que ya tenía?

Comment: En teoría sería hacer lo mismo que estamos intentando, se me ocurre que le elimines el **.empty()** para ver qué tal se comporta. Como tal el contenido debería mostrarse sin problema.

Comment: Debo haberme equivocado copiando tu código, porque lo intente de nuevo y ahora funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Esta es la solución.

Comment: Que bien haber sido de ayuda.